# SharePoint 2013 - Search - Customize Preview Panel (Branding)

Tags: search, sharepoint-server, branding

It is my understanding, that with SharePoint 2013 Search, you have the ability to 'brand' the 'preview' panels based on document set. Is that correct? If so, can someone please provide me some guidance on a starting point? as well, as any reference documentation?

Comment: Are you talking about the Search Result Hover Panel? What do you mean by "brand"?

Comment: Yes, and by branding, I'm talking about adding styling and logos, appropriately.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You just need to create a new search display template. The essential steps are:

1. Copy an existing template
2. Rename the template file
3. Change the look and feel as you need
4. Copy the file back to the Display Templates library
5. Create a result type rule for your content

All of this is detailed here: http://www.ableblue.com/blog/archive/2013/06/05/introduction-to-sharepoint-2013-display-templates/